# DRF override a class function for function based views

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, python-decorators

I have a function-based view (with `api_view` decorator) and I want to make a change to one of the class functions of `APIView`. 
Eg.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
...
def a_view(request, id):
    ...
    return Response({'data': 'testing'}, status=200)
```

and I want to override a function of the APIView (say `initialize_request`) with this.

```
class ViewOverrideMixin(object):
    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do_something
        super(ViewOverrideMixin, self).initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If this was a class based view, I can either place the new function inside the view class or inherit this mixin, how can this be done for function based view? 
Can a decorator to override class function be added?

```
def decorator(viewfn):
    def wrapper(fn):
        # override the APIView function with custom mixin here return the class
        # what would that be?
        return fn
    return wrapper(viewfn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization process and other DRF things are happening inside the [***`@api_view`***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator. If you want to ***tweak*** the functionality, you must write your own custom **`api_view`** decorator.
You can find the source code of the same [here in GitHub](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/ebcd93163a5d0663d16a16d4691df1bbe965d42f/rest_framework/decorators.py#L16)

---

**Note**: Writing a new api_view decorator seems redundant in your case, go with CBV, and override the method